# Why does adding AutoValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute by type not work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core you can validate all non-GET requests by including this line in `Startup.cs` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.0)):

```
services.AddMvc(options => options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute()));
```

However, if you add the filter by type (using `typeof` or the generic `Add<T>` method), the validation doesn't seem to work:

```
// Doesn't work
services.AddMvc(options => options.Filters.Add(typeof(AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute));
// Doesn't work either
services.AddMvc(options => options.Filters.Add<AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute>());
```

See https://github.com/davidgruar/GlobalFilterDemo for a minimal repro.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register the type with the DI container. I just tried and it works.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        // This works
        //options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());

        // These variants don't work
        //options.Filters.Add<AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute>();
        options.Filters.Add(typeof(AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute));
    });

    services.AddScoped<AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute>();
}
```

Comment: Based on my understanding, with the first syntax you are explicitly supplying an instance of the `AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute`, so it worked even you have not registered to the DI

Comment: Do the View Controller still need to be decorated with the ValidateTokenAttribute?