# Using Elsa workflow with antiforgery token

Tags: c#, json.net, .net-5, antiforgerytoken, elsa-workflows

I am using Elsa workflow in my project.
But when I try to send and save the modified workflow or publish the workflow, I get this error:

```
Error occurred: Request with status code 400 failed
```

because i used this code in startup:

```
 var builder = services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(typeof(AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute));
            options.Filters.Add(typeof(AntiforgeryCookieResultFilterAttribute));
            options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new ServiceEndpointModelBinderProvider());
            options.Conventions.Add(new ServiceEndpointActionModelConvention());
        }).AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
        });
```

and if I block this two lines:

```
options.Filters.Add(typeof(AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute));

options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
```

my project will work well

Comment: You have tagged this [tag:datacontractserializer] but `AddNewtonsoftJson` enables the [tag:json.net] serializer, so I'm going to go ahead and update the tags.

Comment: What happens if you remove just `options.Filters.Add(typeof(AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute));` or just `options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();`, does that fix your problem?  Or do you have to remove both of them?

Comment: My project uses these two, and if I remove them, the other parts of the project will not work

Comment: But in your question you wrote, *I block this two lines... my project will work well*, so I am a little confused.  Might you clarify whether you have to remove both lines to resolve the *`Error occurred: Request with status code 400 failed`* error, or whether removing just one or the other is enough?  Also, what asp.net version are you using?

Comment: This might be relevant: [Why does adding AutoValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute by type not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49775349/3744182).

Comment: i'm using .Net 5.0

Answer (score 0):

When you enable anti-forgery, all outgoing requests from the client app (the Elsa Dashboard, which is a SPA) are required to provide an anti-forgery token.

The easiest way might be to follow the instructions provided by this documentation from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-5.0#angularjs

It basically instructs you to:

1. Add a custom ASP.NET Core middleware that writes an anti-forgery token to a cookie.
2. Configure the anti-forgery middleware to read the token from the cookie.

Alternatively, you could write an anti-forgery token straight into HTML, e.g. into some hidden input element when using Razor pages as the host for the Elsa Dashboard, or even as an attribute on the `<elsa-studio-root>` element, and then configure the Axios client (which Elsa uses for making HTTP requests to the server) with middleware that adds the token as a request header.

To configure Axios middleware for Elsa, checkout this discussion: https://github.com/elsa-workflows/elsa-core/discussions/1161#discussioncomment-963103

It's a new feature for Elsa 2.1, so it's not released yet at the time of this writing. The 2.1 prerelease packages are of course available form MyGet if you want to try it.

Comment: I don't use from Elsa dashboard. i straight use from this token:
 <elsa-workflow-definition-editor-screen id="wf" server-url="http://localhost:59952" workflow-definition-id="" monaco-lib-path="/js/monaco-editor/min" />

Comment: Same principle applies: the `<elsa-workflow-definition-editor-screen>` performs HTTP POST requests, which mans you need to supply an anti-forgery token.